# How to set my numeric value to an empty field

Tags: jquery

In one of the input fields on a screen, when a value is entered in the field that is invalid and an alert/error message is raised, the value then is cleared by the code and it shows up as NaN (not a number).  The issue seems to be the following line:

```
            var gift_certificate_code=$('#gift-certificate-code').val();
        if(gift_certificate_code==''){
            alert('Error - Please add gift certificate');
            $('#amount-to-redeem').val('');
            return;
        }
```

This attempts to set the value to blank and this is not digital so it ends up as NaN.  I could set it to 0.00 but I want it to display nothing.  So what do I do?

Comment: Put the rest of the snippet, with one line we'll only be making assumptions about your problem. We need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Indeed, if the `input` has `type="number"` the solution may be different from that if it is `type="text"`...

Comment: It is input type text.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the question so I have to change the answer:<
Please try to be uniform using _ or -, it's pretty confusing..

```
$('#amount-to-redeem').val('');
```

This sets value of "Amount to redeem" to undefined.
To check if there's a giftcard code you have to know if "Gift certificate code" has a value:

```
 if($('#gift_certificate_code').val())
```

If value is set returns true, else false (and launches the first function that clears the "Amount to redeem")

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ares9323/u2vy49z1/50/)